# Doubts about i7 5775c and out of box compatibility with Z97 motherboards

Tags: cpu, motherboard

Am I safe to assume at this day and age that any newly manufactured Z97 motherboard, regardless of the original release date, will be out of box compatible with the i7 5775c or should I look for a specific brand model to be sure?

I'm upgrading from a 2500k, so no way to plug in a CPU to just upgrade the bios before installing the i7.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If it is the Z97E board it supports that processor....http://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/Z97EUSB31/HelpDesk_CPU/

Comment: If the motherboard didn't support the CPU when it was manufactured,  then the firmware, would have to be updated.  Supporting a CPU released after a motherboard is released, allowing support to exist "regardless of the original release date", is an impossible scenario.  You do understand that 2500K and a 5775C are entirely different LGA sockets right?  I suggest you go through the list of supported CPUs for the motherboard you want to purchase and verify its supported though.

Comment: They are hundreds of Intel Z97 motherboards.  Please consider reducing the scope of this question.

Comment: Retailors will often have older revisions of the same motherboard.  Which revision of the motherboard and/or which version of the firmware will be on the motherboard, cannot be predicted.

Comment: Let me try to be specific about models then, those are the ones available for me:

Asrock: Z97 Anniversary, Pro3, Z97 Fatal1ty Killer /
ASUS: Z97A, Z97E and Z97M-Plus /
MSI: Z97s SLI Krait, Z97 Gaming 3, PC Mate

Answer (score 0):

Ask the vendor. If they guarantee compatability out of the box and it happens to not work you can simply send it back.

Otherwise you can search for your specific motherboard of choice and the CPU, ordinarily the manufacturer has a list of compatible CPUs which are supposed to work out of the box.